How does the leakage inductor distribute over multiple coupled inductors?

I am working in LTspice with a triple coupled magnetic inductor.  I chose the factor of coupling to be 90%. L_1 is 1000uH so the uncoupled energy should be 100uH. How does the 100uH energy distribute over those 3 inductors? What would be the series leakage for:

L1
L2
L3
L4


As k=0.9, at what frequency do you want the distribution of energy?

@Antonio51 The frequency is 100kHz

With a factor like kc=0.9, energy should be low, and bandwidth should be "low" ...
You should use "inductor" something like this.
Simulated with "AC Analysis" with microcap v12, the parasitics capacitors and resistors at "minimum", the distribution of energy is like this one ...

At 100 kHz, lost energy should be "high", quasi 20 dB for output vb.
If you take a k higher, it should be better ... and bandwidth too.


And in case of coupling are all "different" for the three inductors ...


Wow. This is much more than I could ask from an answer! Thank you very much!
